# checkValidity() of number input type in Dartlang

Tags: dart

I've the below code to check the input validity, so that the field become '0' if the input is not a number

```
innerInput.onKeyUp.listen((e){
  if(innerInput.checkValidity() == false)innerInput.value='0';
});
```

this works very fine with INTEGER numbers, but one I enter "." followed by any number, and the input field become '0', that is the checkValidity() understood the x.y as something other than valid input number!

any thought?

Comment: What does your input look like? We need to know how you're definingnthe input to be numbers only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.checkValidity()` will check all `constraints`. This means for `input[type=number]` it will check `min, max and step`. So if you want to enter floating point numbers you have to make sure, min, max and step are correct. As you can leave min and max open you at least have to specify `step`. If you want to enter floating point numbers with a precision of 5 digits (e.g. 0.00001) then your `step` attribute has to be `0.00001` or smaller.